# Remove & reinstall summary fields

Tags: summaryfields

We're running Joomla 3.6.2 and CiviCRM 4.7.11, however we recently made some adjustments that prompted us to uninstall the Summary Fields extension. Essentially, it was installed in a different directory than the default settings. We reset the paths and that cause problems. So, we uninstalled and reinstalled, so extensions are now in the default directory. The problem is that when we configure summary fields and set it to update "when the form" is submitted, we receive the error "Error adding custom field 'contribution_amount_last': DB Error: already exists" (same error for other fields as well, like "last donated", etc.). Is there a way to do a complete uninstall of this, or is there a better way to handle this error?

Comment: Working through an uninstall, we've tried to disable the extension in the UI but are presented with the error "DB Error: no such field" and resulting URL is http://ourdomain.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/extensions

No custom fields are visible in the custom fields area, and the tab for summary fields doesn't appear on the contact record. All of the files appear in the default directory for joomla, media/civicrm/ext (previously it was media/civicrm/extensions and it broke when we reset the paths.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up disabling the extension via phpmyadmin, which enabled the "uninstall" link in the UI. Un-installation went fine, and we did a fresh install and now everything appears to be working fine.